# Vue.js Vuex how to use correctly the store.watch() method correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I read about store.watch() , but could not find a valid example ...

> Vuex watch
>   watch(fn: Function, callback: Function, options?: Object): Function
>   Reactively watch fn's return value, and call the callback when the value changes. fn receives the store's state as the first argument, and getters as the second argument. Accepts an optional options object that takes the same options as Vue's vm.$watch method.
>   To stop watching, call the returned unwatch function.

I have a Vuex action for user sign in with Firebase

```
signUserIn ({commit}, payload) {
  commit(types.SET_LOADING, true)
  commit(types.CLEAR_ERROR)
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
  .then((user) => {
    commit(types.SET_LOADING, false)
    const newUser = { id: user.uid, name: user.displayName, email: user.email, photoUrl: user.photoURL }
    commit(types.SET_USER, newUser)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    commit(types.SET_LOADING, false)
    commit(types.SET_ERROR, error)
  })
},
```

I am dispatching this action from my Signin vue component

In my business case, signin fails as the user is not already registered, so an erro is raised and commited in store
but in my component, I don't grab the error right after dispatch 
so I have a loading value in store set to true/false
and I need to watch it change...  so I try to use the store.watch()

**onSignIn method ( after validation)**

```
    this.$store.dispatch('signUserIn', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
      console.log('loading...: ', this.$store.getters.loading)
      this.$store.watch(this.$store.getters.loading, () => {
        console.log('loaded')
        console.log('onSIgnin error', this.error.code)
      })
```

but I get the Vuex error

```
 Error: [vuex] store.watch only accepts a function
```

I am passing a function, isn't it ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument for watch is a function that recieves the state as the first argument and getters as the second. So access the getters like so and the return value is the one being watched.

```
      this.$store.watch((state, getters) => getters.loading, () => {
        console.log('loaded')
        console.log('onSIgnin error', this.error.code)
      })
```